# App crashes when I include setContentView and setText

Tags: java, android, textview, setcontentview

This is my first android app, pretty confused and not sure if I'm doing it right. My app is intended to be a countdown app for a specific date

Here is what my MainActivity class looks like. I replaced ... where the code I wrote relating to the actual countdown variable was - I have tested it in the console and that part of the program works fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        counting();
    }

    public void counting() {
        ...
        String reading = days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes remaining";
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_first);
        textView.setText(reading);
    }
}
```

It runs and shows me the 'hello' text string specified in strings.xml

```
 <string name="hello_first_fragment">hello</string>
```

as long as I get rid of both the

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

as well as the

```
        textView.setText(reading);
```

lines under my counting function, but I don't want it to show that string, I would rather it display the value of the variable I want to choose. If I include either or both of them, it crashes the app.

I'm wondering if maybe I have the textview ID wrong - I got that from my fragment_first.xml file which has

```
"android:id="@+id/textview_first""
```

under TextView.

Another thing I have tested is with just making the textView.setText field have a non-variable string in it, like

```
            textView.setText("reading");
```

but it does the same thing

I'm not sure if I might have to somehow remove the string line in strings.xml somehow or edit it, I tried just deleting it and it wouldn't compile.

Anyone have any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: delete `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in counting method and show logcat output with information of the crash please.

Comment: @GGK stands for Ukraine first time using stackoverflow so sorry if this is the wrong etiquette but it says it's too long so I've posted it on pastebin https://pastebin.com/Djutb8Lh thank you for the quick reply

Comment: @creamsiclecat Are you using Activity or Fragment ?

Comment: @Ticherhaz FreePalestine 
I did 'basic activity' which I edited down because I didn't actually need all the functions, not sure if that's where my issue could be coming from. Do you have one you might recommend instead? I haven't done that much so I'm 100% okay starting over

Comment: the logcat says, that textview is null